# Multi column sorting in GWT CellTable

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT 2.5.1. I have a CellTable and I want to be able to sort by more than one column. Basically, I want to be able to do combined sorting. For e.g, I have 4 columns. ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD. When I click on ColA, it should sort by that column. Now, with shift key pressed, if I click on ColB, ColA should remain the primary column and ColB should become the secondary column. And again, if I click on say Col D with shift key pressed, then sorting should be first by ColA, then ColB and then ColD. I have comparators written for every column. So basically, single column sorting works without any problem.

I tried to do

```
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColD);
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColB);
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColA);
ColumnSortEvent.fire( usersTable, usersTable.getColumnSortList());
```

But this only sorts by ColA.

Has anyone tried to do something similar? Any pointers would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Let me simplify my requirement. Lets say I have a button. On button click I want to sort the list first by ColA, then ColB and then by ColD. ColB and ColD become the secondary sort columns. As far as I understand, myTable.getColumnSortList() only maintains the header state, i.e. the information that the table was sorted by which all columns(only one at a time, not simultaneously) and in which order asc or desc. Even if we do ColumnSortEvent.fire( usersTable, usersTable.getColumnSortList()); it will only sort the table by the newest added column in the list(single column sorting), in the order determined by ColumnSortInfo object for that column.

My idea is to achieve multi column sorting like the one shown in the example below: http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Comment: I use similar code, and it works fine. When do you fire the sort event?

Comment: Please see my clarification below.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that "the ColumnSortList contains the ordered list of sorted columns." - list, not a single column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Though I was not satisfied with my solution, I figured I would share it, just in case anyone has the same problem.  It seems to me that the fire event only takes the last column pushed.  By invoking it after every push you'll get the desired result.  Lame, I know, but better that nothing.

---

```
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColD);
ColumnSortEvent.fire( usersTable, usersTable.getColumnSortList());
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColB);
ColumnSortEvent.fire( usersTable, usersTable.getColumnSortList());
myTable.getColumnSortList().push(ColA);
ColumnSortEvent.fire( usersTable, usersTable.getColumnSortList());
```

Answer (score 0):

ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler.onColumnSort() only sorts one column; the most recently pushed to the SortColumnList.  See that ColumnSortEvent.getColumn(), called by onColumnSort(), only returns index 0 of sortList.

I think GWT is broken in this regard.  A ColumnSortEvent is created with a SortColumnLIST (emphasis mine), however only the first column of the list matters.

As another answer pointed out, the fix is to sort multiple times, in the reverse order of column precedence: sort the secondary column before the primary.